# Stuck the ball in the board (pingpong game)

Tags: c#, winforms

this game isn't completed yet, i've created the part where the ball hits the board, but there's problem in playing and that's the ball stucking in the board. For a better comprehension and understaning i've attached a image down below , plz watch it and lemme know of your take on this bug.

```
   public partial class PingPong : Form
{
    public PingPong()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 30;
    }


    int mx = 5;
    int my = 5;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(boardCenter.Bounds))
        {
            mx = mx * -1;
            my = my * 1;
        }
        else if (ball.Location.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - ball.Height)
        {
            mx = mx * 1;
            my = my * -1;
        }
        else if (ball.Location.Y <= 0)
        {
            mx = mx * 1;
            my = my * -1;
        }

        else if (ball.Location.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - ball.Width)
        {
            mx = mx * -1;
            my = my * 1;
        }


        ball.Location = new Point(ball.Location.X + mx, ball.Location.Y + my);

    }

    private void PingPong_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            board.Location = new Point(board.Location.X, board.Location.Y - 4);

        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            board.Location = new Point(board.Location.X, board.Location.Y + 4);
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: For a better comprehension and understaning i've I put a video https://youtu.be/WSZxw42qR-E

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me (base on the video you provided) that your logic is actually right, the problem looks to be that the ball is hitting the board from behind and therefore the collision rapidly being calculated between the left side of the window and the back side of the board.

You should modify your code so that the collision with the left side of the window is calculated at the same X position as the board. For example, if the board X position is fixed at 20 from the left side of the screen, the make the collision between the ball and the left side of the window at 20, this way the ball will never be able to reach the back of the board. (Same principle applies to the right side of the screen and the second board).